# AngularJS how to print JSON format message?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to print JSON format message, which is generated by input forms.
Any idea?

If user click submit, a JSON must be print out on the bottom of the display note following this format:

```
[   
{
“question”: “Write down Nhat’s email”,
    “answer”: “nhat@taie.com.au”,
    “inline”: true
},
{
<% NEXT QUESTION/ANSWER %>
},
{
<%…%>
}
]
```

Here is my current code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>Angular - My Notes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input.blockInput {
          display: block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
    <div ng-controller="Note">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" ng-model= "item.Question">
        <input ng-class="{'blockInput': !item.inlineChecked}" type="text" placeholder= "{{item.Note}}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="item.inlineChecked"> Inline
      </div>
      <button ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Note = function($scope){
        $scope.items = [
          { Question: "Question", Note: "enter text..."}
        ];

        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            inlineChecked: false,
            Question: "Question",
            Note: "enter text..."
          });
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are automatically converted in template outputs. Just write `{{items}}` in your template to show the json-formatted content of `$scope.items`.

Comment: please tell me what you don't understand, there is much to explain :)

Comment: thanks! when I just create div and write {{items}}, there is nothing shows

Comment: currently, it's working: showing the json message now

Comment: `{{items}}` must be inside the `div` with `ng-controller="Note"`